# setState callback function is not getting called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React. Here, I have a checkbox which selects all the elements. On click of that I call one method:

```
handleCheckBox = (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    console.log("calling this");
    const updates = {};
    for (const item of [...this.props.untracked.content]) {
      updates[item.resumeId] = "unTracked";
    }
    for (const item of [...this.props.tracked.content]) {
      updates[item.resumeId] = "tracked";
    }
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      selectedValue: {
        ...oldState.selectedValue,
        ...updates,
      }
    }, () => {
      console.log("going in this");
    }));
  } else {
    const reset = {};
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: {
        ...reset
      }
    })
  }
}
```

When I click on the checkbox it selects all the values and also their respective checkbox. In doing so, `going in this` gets printed in the console. Now, if I click on the respective checkbox one or two, and then if I try to click on the checkbox on which the given method is getting called, that time it does not get called.

So, the callfunction is not getting called that time. So, is there any reason why it might not be calling?

Comment: In theory, it would only get called every odd number of clicks right? Considering the logic you implemented.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState(oldState => ({
  selectedValue: {
    ...oldState.selectedValue,
    ...updates,
  }
}, () => {
  console.log("going in this");
}));
```

is equivalent to

```
this.setState(oldState => () => {
  console.log("going in this");
});
```

because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). You probably meant to pass two arguments to the call, like this:

```
this.setState(oldState => ({
  selectedValue: {
    ...oldState.selectedValue,
    ...updates,
  }
}), () => {
  console.log("going in this");
});
```

Notice the difference in how the parentheses are placed.